# Returning matplotlib plots using telegram bot

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, telegram-bot

This code is from [here](https://djangostars.com/blog/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-telegram-bot/)
I have the following code for a telegram bot which i am building:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import requests 

from bottle import (  
    run, post, response, request as bottle_request
)

BOT_URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot128secretns/'  
def get_chat_id(data):  
    """
    Method to extract chat id from telegram request.
    """
    chat_id = data['message']['chat']['id']

    return chat_id

def get_message(data):  
    """
    Method to extract message id from telegram request.
    """
    message_text = data['message']['text']

    return message_text

def send_message(prepared_data):  
    """
    Prepared data should be json which includes at least `chat_id` and `text`
    """ 
    message_url = BOT_URL + 'sendMessage'
    requests.post(message_url, json=prepared_data)   

def get_ticker(text):  
    stock = f'^GSPC'
    start = datetime.date(2000,1,1)
    end = datetime.date.today()
    data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo',start, end)
    plot = data.plot(y='Open') 
    return plot


def prepare_data_for_answer(data):  
    answer = get_ticker(get_message(data))

    json_data = {
        "chat_id": get_chat_id(data),
        "text": answer,
    }

    return json_data

@post('/')
def main():  
    data = bottle_request.json

    answer_data = prepare_data_for_answer(data)
    send_message(answer_data)  # <--- function for sending answer

    return response  # status 200 OK by default

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

When i run this code i am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type AxesSubplot is not JSON serializable
```

What this code is suppose to do is take ticker symbols from telegram app and return its chart back.

I know this is because json does not handle images. 
What can i do to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I'm a bit late to the party. Here is a possible solution below, though I didn't test it. Hope it works or at least gives you a way to go about solving the issue :)

```
import datetime
from io import BytesIO

import requests
from pandas_datareader import data as web
from bottle import (
    run, post, response, request as bottle_request
)

BOT_URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot128secretns/'

def get_chat_id(data):
    """
    Method to extract chat id from telegram request.
    """
    chat_id = data['message']['chat']['id']

    return chat_id

def get_message(data):
    """
    Method to extract message id from telegram request.
    """
    message_text = data['message']['text']

    return message_text

def send_photo(prepared_data):
    """
    Prepared data should be json which includes at least `chat_id` and `plot_file`
    """
    data = {'chat_id': prepared_data['chat_id']}
    files = {'photo': prepared_data['plot_file']}

    requests.post(BOT_URL + 'sendPhoto', json=data, files=files)

def get_ticker(text):
    stock = f'^GSPC'
    start = datetime.date(2000,1,1)
    end = datetime.date.today()
    data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo',start, end)
    plot = data.plot(y='Open')

    return plot

def prepare_data_for_answer(data):
    plot = get_ticker(get_message(data))

    # Write the plot Figure to a file-like bytes object:
    plot_file = BytesIO()
    fig = plot.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(plot_file, format='png')
    plot_file.seek(0)

    prepared_data = {
        "chat_id": get_chat_id(data),
        "plot_file": plot_file,
    }

    return prepared_data

@post('/')
def main():
    data = bottle_request.json

    answer_data = prepare_data_for_answer(data)
    send_photo(answer_data)  # <--- function for sending answer

    return response  # status 200 OK by default

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

The idea is not to send a message using the `sendMessage` Telegram API endpoint, but to send a photo file by using the `sendPhoto` endpoint. Here, we use `savefig` call in the `prepare_data_for_answer` function body to convert `AxesSubplot` instance, that we get as a return value from the `get_ticker` function, to a file-like `BytesIO` object, which we then send as a photo to Telegram using `send_photo` function (previously named as `send_message`).

Answer (score 1):

## You may use bob-telegram-tools

```
from bob_telegram_tools.bot 
import TelegramBot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


token = '<your_token>'
user_id = int('<your_chat_id>')
bot = TelegramBot(token, user_id)

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

bot.send_plot(plt)

# This method delete the generetad image
bot.clean_tmp_dir()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a matplotlib figure directly. You will need to convert it to bytes and then send it as a multipart message.

`data.plot` will return a `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object. You can save convert the figure to bytes like this

```py
import StringIO
img = StringIO.StringIO()
plot.fig.savefig(img, format='png')
img.seek(0)
```

[yukuku/telebot](https://github.com/yukuku/telebot) has some good code on how to send the image as a message. Check this line [here](https://github.com/yukuku/telebot/blob/7579a97f59698569bb176be35fa27b1ce5767cc0/main.py#L97).